# enable textbox when checkbox checked in a TABLE ROW

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `submit.cshtml` is:

```
<table id="scDetails" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>IsChecked</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fbacks)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EditorTemplate is for -  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fbacks)` (Fbacks.cshtml)

```
<tr>
  <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Item)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Item)
  </td>
  <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comment)</td>
</tr>
```

What I need is:

When I check the checkbox, textbox should be enabled and when uncheck, textbox should disabled.

Comment: Which version of `jQuery` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    $(this).parent().next().find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', !isChecked);
}); 

// OR

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', !isChecked);
    });
```

Comment: Do i need to specify any Id on EditorTemplate? Fbacks.cshtml page? or Submit.cshtml page

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find("textarea").prop("disabled", ! this.checked);
});
```

Comment: This need to be written on submit.cshtml or Fbacks.cshtml page? Do I need to replace "textarea" with "textbox". Please.

Answer (score 1):

You should add event to checkbox

```
$('#Fbacks').click (function ()
{
     var thisCheck = $(this);
     if (thischeck.is (':checked'))
     {
       $('#Comment').prop('disabled', true);
     }else{
       $('#Comment').prop('disabled', false);
     }
});
```

in this case `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fbacks)` `id = 'Fbacks'`

Comment: Do i need to specify any Id on EditorTemplate?

Comment: This need to be written on Submit.cshtml or? EditorTemplate page?

Comment: This can be written in any place, The main think that this code executed after document.ready(). On the bissuness logic i will be put it on EditorTemplate as it logic of editForm.

Comment: but the best place of js code is separate file, which should be included in master page